# How to find birth place for Charles Klein born in Russia Sept 2, 1883

Tags: 19th-century, russia, historical-gazetteer

Charles or Charlie Klein’s World War II draft registration says he was born in *Pullin, Russia*.

I have not been able to find this place and wondered if spelling is a mispronunciation.

Typed [U.S. World War II Draft Registration Card (image) for Charlie Klein](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:S3HY-DH4Q-PVS?i=413&wc=SPQT-ZNL%3A179762801%3Fcc%3D1861144&cc=1861144) can be viewed at FamilySearch. (Index entry at [FamilySearch](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:XPY4-RY6))

Comment: While looking for the entry referred to in the question, I found a WWI Draft card for a Charles Klein in New York City [at Family Search](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:KXYG-2QS).  May not be the same Charles Kiein, but his place of birth was given as "Russian Poland." Note that having somehing other than a town name in the "town or county" field is not unusual.

Comment: @bgwhiele I edited the link in your comment because the trailing bracket was getting picked up as part of the URL and the link was returning an error message.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  Have you located any other records for Charlie -- like the 1940 Census?

Comment: Thank you for all comments. These have been most helpful and more than I have ever gotten in other places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably that can be an urban-type settlement in Russian Empire Zhytomyr district. (now in Zhytomyr oblast of Ukraine) called [Pulyny or Pulin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chervonoarmiisk). Now In 1935 name of the settlement was changed to Chervonoarmejsk. Till 1793 it had belong to Poland.

Probably, he is originated from a [german settlement](https://www.sggee.org/pipermail/ger-poland-volhynia/2001-December/013032.html) in that area.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE! If you need more information about the site, you'll find it in the usual places, [help] and [meta].